# buffered d2i X509_CRL using openssl

Tags: c++, linux, openssl, x509certificate, x509

I am using d2i_X509_CRL_bio(bio, NULL) from openssl to reach revocation list and construct my database from a 40MB of .crl file. but when I call this function, it consumes all of my RAM (I have very low memory and no swap area in linux) and I am getting "Out of memory: Kill process" error.

I also tried d2i_X509_CRL_fp function, but it has no difference.

Is there any chance to get revocation list using some kind of buffered system and create my database entry without getting out of memory?

thanks in advance,